# Задание длины линии в сантиметрах и ее рисование (Wpf, Canvas)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Интересует задание длины линии в сантиметрах и рисование такой линии (в WPF на Canvas).
Пожалуйста, кто с этим сталкивался, подскажите ссылки, источники.
Делаю так, програмно получаю значение dpi (по оси ОХ и по оси ОY равно 144), преобразую в точки (вирт.пиксели) на сантиметр (равно  56,69 точек\см), от заданной длины в сантиметрах (например, 10 см) перехожу в длину в точках (равно 566,93), рисую эту линию на Canvas - в результате эта длина линии (в см) процентов на 30 (меряю линейкой) больше исходно заданной длины в см. Mасштаб экрана установлен 150%.
dpi (точек на дюйм) определяю так

PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this); double dpiX = -1, dpiY = -1; if (source != null) { dpiX = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11; dpiY = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22; }

Comment: чего именно dpi ? масштаб того, где "меряю линейкой", какой?

Comment: Кстати, да, эта величина - "процентов тридцать" - напоминает "масштаб по умолчанию" в некоторых ноутах, где по умолчанию установлено "125%"